# Frida server not enough privileges

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

Im running Android within an Anbox setup, I downloaded the frida-server version for Anbox the android-x86_64.

I followed this steps

```
adb push frida-server-12.11.18-android-x86_64
 /data/local/tmp/
adb shell "chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/frida-server-12.11.18-android-x86_64
"
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/frida-server-12.11.18-android-x86_64
 &"
```

Ok now comes my issue if I try to

```
# frida-ps -Uai
Failed to enumerate applications: unable to find process with name 'system_server'
```

But without the ai works, the problem is that does not have visibility of running applications

```
frida-ps -U
 PID  Name
----  ------------------------------------
2333  frida-server-12.11.18-android-x86_64
1571  logcat
2335  logcat
  48  sh
```

My guess is that this is related to permissions of the frida-server running inside the Anbox, I have tried to launch it as root but it crashes the whole environment.

```
x86_64:/data/local/tmp $ ls -ll                                                                                                                       
total 110648
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u1_root u1_root 56645256 2020-10-15 16:11 frida-server-12.11.18-android-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root        4096 2020-10-17 07:41 re.frida.server
```

Any clue on how to give visibility to the frida-server ?

Comment: As you are using a non-Google-certified Android system another possibility can be that the process `system_server` has just been renamed and therefore frida can't find it.

Comment: Sounds like an Anbox issue. I haven't run into an issue like with using AVD or x86. Only thing would be to double check you're using the correct version of frida-server.

Comment: In this release notes https://frida.re/news/releases/, said Anbox is supported. Hmm, but I still don't manage to make it works.

Comment: Exactly in sub title `Changes in 14.2.15`, just search that term.

Comment: Need to run frida-server in root shell, means `su` need to be called before.

Answer (score 4):

You have to be a sudo user

**Note:** Make sure Frida-Server is the same version as your Frida install.
You can safely run a newer version on the host side though, as long as the major version is the same.

**Tested**

```
user@user:~$ adb push frida-server /data/local/tmp/frida-server
user@user:~$ adb shell
x86_64:/ $ su
x86_64:/ # chmod 777 ./data/local/tmp/frida-server
x86_64:/ # ./data/local/tmp/frida-server
```

Answer (score 1):

After debugging this issue today I have discovered that frida-agent-32.so causes zygote to crash for some reason. After zygote crashes Anbox immediately crashes as well.

Because I am lazy, I have decided to look for a workaround instead of fixing this bug. After trial and error I have found that this bug is not present in the 64 bit version of the agent (frida-agent-64.so). Therefore, after disabling 32 bit agent Frida can still inject and execute every 64 bit or libhoudini (arm/arm64) app.

In order to prevent frida-server from injecting the agent to zygote (32 bit) I have simply modified two lines, see [the last commit](https://github.com/liornm/frida-core/commit/7a5d8ffcad7209f5e28265ae360504a6a09c96b2).

If you want to avoid the hassle of compiling frida-server yourself you can just use my [compiled version](https://github.com/liornm/frida-core/releases/tag/anbox-workaround).

Comment: I was trying your workaround, but seems not working. `frida-ps -U` does not display the android app process.

Comment: Ah, I did not run frida-server in root shell. Solved.